# Creating a custom two-dimensional Array with different length in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to java script and want to declare an 2-D array in java script

```
var ProgramSubTabs = $("#ProgramTabs").val();
var subTypes = $("#subTypes").val();
var programMonths = $("#programMonths").val();
var subTypesArray = subTypes.split(',');
var programMonthsArray = programMonths.split(',');
var TotalTabArr = new Array() ;
if (!TotalTabArr[0]) 
TotalTabArr[0] = []; 

for(var subTypearr = 0;subTypearr<subTypesArray.length;subTypearr++){
    TotalTabArr["'"+subTypesArray[subTypearr]+"'"] = [];
    for(var monthsarr = 0;monthsarr<programMonthsArray.length;monthsarr++){
        TotalTabArr["'"+subTypesArray[subTypearr]+"'"]["'"+programMonthsArray[monthsarr]+"'"] = subTypearr+' test String '+monthsarr;
    }
}
```

what is wrong in this code Please help.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for questions like "why isn't this code working?" Instead, describe the problem you are trying to solve, paste the code you tried, paste any errors (if present), and tell us the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is working quite fine.

I've put it into fiddle, and looks like the logs give the right data...

But, I don't use upper case to start var names

```
var programSubTabs = $('#ProgramTabs').val();
var totalTabArr = new Array();
```

and I skipped your first if that was not needed...

```
if (!TotalTabArr[0]) 
totalTabArr[0] = [];
```

Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/djcw7h8h/4/

Check the console.

Hope it helps